# Allow multiple CORS domain in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

How do I allow multiple domains for CORS in express in a simplified way.

I have

```
 cors: {
        origin: "www.one.com";
    }

    app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", cors.origin);
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            next();
        });
```

This works when there is only one domain mentioned in `origin`

But if I want to have `origin` as an array of domains and I want to allow CORS for all the domains in the origin array, I would have something like this -

```
cors: {
            origin: ["www.one.com","www.two.com","www.three.com"];
        }
```

But then the problem is this below code would not work -

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", cors.origin);
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
                next();
            });
```

How do I make `res.header` take an array of domains via `cors.origin` ?

Comment: what's the problem with using "*" instead of a domain or two?

Comment: * would not put any CORS filter. * would basically allow all domain which I clearly do not want.

Comment: just remember the cors only affects browsers, so security has nothing to do with cors.

Comment: Yes agreed, but is it a good practice to put * ?

Comment: using "\*" makes it easier to scale and move stuff around later without hard-coding domains. i don't know of any major downsides, and anyone can still use JS to ping your server and show your images/videos without CORS. with postMessage(), "*" is a bad idea, but with CORS it's groovy.

Comment: @dandavis cors does only affect browsers so its security concern is for the user, not your server

Comment: @dandavis Your comments were made 5 years ago, so your views may have changed, but for future readers, CORS _is_ about security. It's the first line of defense against cross site request forgery if you're using cookies (that's why browsers block cross origin requests by default). The "*" policy means any site can make a request as your user (assuming no other CSRF mitigations). If that user is an admin on your service, a malicious site can do a lot of damage.

Answer (score 40):

The value of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` must be a string, not a list. So to make it dynamic you need to get the requesting origin from the `Origin` HTTP request header, check it against your array of authorized origins. If it's present, then add that origin as the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header; otherwise, use a default value, which would prohibit unauthorized domains from accessing the API.

There is no native implementation for this. You can do it yourself using the code below.

```
cors: {
  origin: ["www.one.com","www.two.com","www.three.com"],
  default: "www.one.com"
}

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  const origin = cors.origin.includes(req.header('origin').toLowerCase()) ? req.headers.origin : cors.default;
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: if you go to jquery.com and in the developers tools console make a `$.ajax` to `www.one.com`, what value you get on `req.header('host')`?, in my tests I get `www.one.com` wich would make the check think that this is an allowed domain, can anyone confirm this or clarify what is wrong in my test?

Comment: Change `req.header('host')` to `req.header('origin')`

Answer (score 24):

Using Node, cors middleware, make sure you leave the / off the url, OR ELSE cors could fail if the url in the browser is displayed without it. I.e.

```
var corsOptions = {
origin: ["http://www.example.com/","http://localhost:3000"],
optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // For legacy browser support
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Failed and would give me the cors error because the browser would display/read the url as http://www.example.com, where below worked and is more inclusive and should work for http://www.example.com and anything beyond that, i.e. http://www.example.com/ or http://www.example.com/blogs/1, etc

```
var corsOptions = {
origin: ["http://www.example.com","http://localhost:3000"],
optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // For legacy browser support
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Answer (score 10):

## Simplest way

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors({ origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "https://origin2.com"] }));
```

This will allow request from `localhost:3000` and `origin2.com`

Answer (score 5):

In fact, Access-Control-Allow-Origin header should be the same value as the Origin header as long as you want to allow it.

So base on your code just

```
cors: {
    origin: ["www.one.com","www.two.com","www.three.com"]
}



app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
            let origin = req.headers.origin;
            if(cors.origin.indexOf(origin) >= 0){
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
            }         
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            next();
        });
```

Comment: @nameless Nice thought, but that domain wouldn't be allowed: `["www.one.com","www.two.com","www.three.com"].indexOf("https://www.one.com.my.malicious.site.com") === -1`

Answer (score 2):

Hi i want to share my solution: !!!
These code works if you are using a remote server and developing on localhost (webpack or another dev environment) Cheers!!

```
let ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://serverabc.com", "http://localhost:8080"];
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let origin = req.headers.origin;
    let theOrigin = (ALLOWED_ORIGINS.indexOf(origin) >= 0) ? origin : ALLOWED_ORIGINS[0];
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", theOrigin);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

    next();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
var cors = {
    origin: (origin, callback)=>{
       if(["www.one.com","www.two.com","www.three.com"].includes(origin)){
          callback(null, origin);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Click **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77258686/13607767)** to find a detailed answer on how to use `cors` to whitelist specific domains i.e. allow only specific domains to access your backend endpoints securely.

I have used `cors` recently. This is the better way which I could come up with that works well, has better control and security.

Basically, add allowed domains in `.env` file. So that no one knows your allowed domains.
`ALLOWED_ORIGINS=https://foo.example1 https://foo.example2`

Then, create a middleware for `customCorsOptions` as per your requirement.

lastly, use `cors` in your main server file.

```
app.use(cors(customCorsOptions));
```