# Express CORS domain whitelist

Tags: node.js, rest, express, cors

I am using this module to handle cors requests https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors
I need to restrict all domains except whitelisted

From official CORS module example:

```
var whitelist = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com'];
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function(origin, callback){
    var originIsWhitelisted = whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
    callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
  }
};

app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next){
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.'});
});
```

Which I have changed to this to make it work:

```
var origin;
var corsOptions;
app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
    origin = req.get('origin');
    var whitelist = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com'];
    corsOptions = {
        origin: function (origin, callback) {
            var originIsWhitelisted = whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
            callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
        }
    };
    next();
});
app.post('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.' });
});
```

Then I run test from `http://localhost:8080` by posting to `app.post('/products/:id'...)` I expected it should not be executed because `http://localhost:8080` is not whitelisted but actually it did. Any idea why and how to fix that?

Also I  didadd `cors(corsOptions)` to watch but it is saying - `not available`

Comment: Why does the original example from the `cors` module readme not work for you? Your code is actually doing the same exact thing, except deferring it until a request is received.

Comment: @mscdex I did debug a bit more and actually original thing is working. But I am a bit confused why line `res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.' });` getting executed but the  response I am getting is actually `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `corsOptions` is still `undefined` when `cors(corsOptions)` is called (effectively the same as `cors()`) since `cors(corsOptions)` is evaluated immediately during startup.

Comment: Ho `express` understands that it has to return `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` error rather than `res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.' });` ? I can see that line `res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.' });` is gets executed when sending request from `non whitelisted` domain is that because `cors(corsOptions)`  gets involved?

Comment: `cors(corsOptions)` returns a middleware function. That function gets called for every POST request to `/products/:id` but before the actual route handler gets called. This allows the `cors` middleware to deny the request before it ever reaches the route handler. You can pass as many middleware to `app.post()` or any other function that accepts middleware/route handlers and it will process them in order.

Comment: I am still confused however the response is seams to be right but route code is always gets executed which is not quite right because I do not need route code to be executed in case of `non whitelisted` domain. Just put separate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393965/node-express-cors-and-routes on that.

Comment: So are you saying the documented example should work or not?  It doesn't work for me unless I implement the same fix the OP did.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution in `nodejs expressjs`.

1. add allowed origins in `.env` file.  so that no one knows which domains you whitelisted.
   `ALLOWED_ORIGINS=https://foo.example1 https://foo.example2`
2. Create a middleware for `customCorsOptions`.

```
const customCorsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    const allowedOrigins = process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGINS.split(" ");
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error("Request from unauthorized origin"));
    }
  },
};

export default customCorsOptions;
```

3. Use `cors`.

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";

import customCorsOptions from "./middleware/customCorsOptions.js";

/* CONFIGURATION */
dotenv.config(); // This needs to be configured first to use env variables everywhere
const app = express();
app.use(cors(customCorsOptions));

// other codes in your server.js
```