# Node express cors and routes

Tags: node.js, rest, express, cors

I am using CORS https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors to allow `whitedomain` list.

```
   var whitelist = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com'];
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function(origin, callback){
    var originIsWhitelisted = whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
    callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
  }
};

app.post('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(0);
    res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.' });        
});
```

In case of `non whitedomain` the server returns `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` which is fine but at the same time I can see on debug that the lines `res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.' });` and `console.log(0);` still gets executed - `console.log(0);` printed `0` in console on server side which is something I do not wan't in that case.

So lets say if is writhing to database:

```
app.post('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
        writeToDatabase();
        res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.' });            
    });
```

This way `writeToDatabase();` will always be executed. But I want to avoid that because I do not need to write any stuff in to database in case of `non whitelisted` domain.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can make the **HTTP** request **Preflighted**, by adding a custom request header refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). 
That way the following **route** will not get executed in first place if the origin is not allowed. As it sends **OPTIONS** request first time which verifies the CORS and then sends the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to use if to filter the request inside the app.post 
so for example,

```
app.post('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
        if(req.header[origin]===whitelisted){
        writeToDatabase();
        res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.' }); }           
    });
```

Comment: Yeah that is sort of `code smell` solution that has to be repeated for each protected route.

Answer (score 0):

Try to throw an error inside your `corsOptions`, as shown in this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77258686/13607767).
Basically, throw an error when `originIsWhitelisted` is false. That should solve the issue.

```
var customCorsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    const allowedOrigins = process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGINS.split(" ");
    var originIsWhitelisted = allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
    if (originIsWhitelisted) {
      callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
    } else {
      callback(new Error("UNAUTHORIZED"));
    }
  },
};
```