# What does the function call app.use(cors()) do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I know that we cannot have access to an API that has a different domain then ours. However, I see many people installing the `cors` module in [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) to use APIs and then using it like so:

```
app.use(cors());
```

What does it actually do? How does this function enable `cors` on the server?

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Comment: It likely enables [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)?

Comment: Ok but to access other APIs or to be accessed by someone? Just by declaring this line I can access other APIs on the web?

Comment: You're configuring *your* server to be accessed by anyone, not client access to other servers. CORS is not a proxy

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 21):

#### Abstract

As you said, it enables [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (cross-origin resource sharing). In order for your server to be accessible by other origins (domains).

#### What it really does

Calling `use(cors())` will enable the `express server` to respond to preflight requests.

A preflight request is basically an `OPTION` request sent to the server before the actual request is sent, in order to ask which origin and which request options the server accepts.

So CORS is basically a set of headers sent by the server to the browser.
Calling `cors()` without any additional information will set the following defaults:

```
{
  "origin": "*",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  "preflightContinue": false,
  "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
}
```

These are translated into these headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Status Code: 204
```

It is basically making your server accessible to any domain that requests a resource from your server via a browser.

You can check all the [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) `cors` configurations at *[cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)* (GitHub).

You can also read more about browser `cors` at *[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)* ([MDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDN_Web_Docs)).

Answer (score -2):

[CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is a feature that restricts a web browser from making an API request from one domain to other domain.

E.g., your front end is in https://domain1.com and your back end is in https://domain2.com. Now the CORS policy error occurs. To solve this error in your back end, update the main JavaScript file. (I'm using Node.js as the backend.)

Solution (1)

```
app.use(cors())
```

Solution (2)

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://domain1.com',
}
app.get('/', cors(corsOptions), (req, res) => {
  res.json()
})
```

Visit the link for more information: [Express.js CORS](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).