# GET/POST in axios not working but fetch works

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios, fetch-api

I have a REST API hosted on Heroku. It consists of Express, NodeJS and MongoDB(mongoose as orm and MongoDB Atlas as well). I am using MERN stack. Beginner here

The API Link:

```
<a href="https://mern-deploy-test-adib.herokuapp.com/api/todos">/api/todos</a>
```

The API works just fine with Postman and VS code's API plugin. It also works perfectly fine on the localhost.

But when I try to GET/POST using axios, it gives:

> Error: "Network Error"

But `fetch()` works just fine. So does Postman.

Also the I see cors warning in the console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://mern-deploy-test-adib.herokuapp.com/api/todos. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://localhost:3000/’)

but I set the cors like so:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000/', credentials: true }))
```

Interestingly the API worked in localhost but after deploying it doesn't work with axios.

I have set `cors origin: 'http://localhost:3000/'`
And I checked the headers of both the fetch and axios GET request. They are literally the same.

The request header has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin  http://localhost:3000/`

BTW my frontend is hosted on `localhost:3000`

So why is this happening?
Why is axios not working but fetch is.

Edit: here's the code for both axios and fetch request.

```js
//fetch
fetch(`https://heroku-api-link/api/todos`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err))

//axios
axios.get(`https://heroku-api-link/api/todos`)
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

EDIT#2:
I tried an axios request using an editor on my phone (SPCK editor). The request was successful. I just don't get why it's not working from my pc.

Comment: Please add your code; for both, fetch and axios.

Comment: Done. Just a basic get request.

Comment: "it returns me the server error inside the catch block I set in server.js " — And what is that error?

Comment: "I have set cors origin: '*' " — How? Where?

Comment: It's a 400 bad request error and returns { message: "Sorry, bad request" }

Comment: I set cors in express. `app.use(cors({ origin: '*', credentials: true }))`

Comment: Did you also install cors package to your node server? Could you check this answer too? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45049763/1549080

Comment: This can be usefull too. https://jonathanmh.com/how-to-enable-cors-in-express-js-node-js/ Btw I suggest you to check your Heroku logs. I believe your CORS is not successfully enabled for localhost requests.

Comment: add ```app.use(cors());``` in server.js

Comment: I tried both `app.use(cors())` and `app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000" }))`

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out!!
Actually it's the origin link I set in cors. I set the origin to `http://localhost:3000/`. But interestingly the client origin (also `http://localhost:3000/`) didn't match the origin in the server.
But when I changed the server cors origin to `http://localhost:3000`, removing the `'/'` from the origin fixed the issue. I don't know why it didn't  worked but I am glad it did. Now I need explanation why it worked. Is it something to do with specific route? Like adding the `'/'` makes it so that only the 'Home' route would work?