# How to connect front and backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I try to connect my local backend with the fronte

```js
   axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:5000/api/user/login",
      withCredentials: true,
      data: {
        email,
        password,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.errors) {
          emailError.innerHTML = res.data.errors.email;
          passwordError.innerHTML = res.data.errors.password;
        } else {
          window.location = "/";
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

nd Reactjs. The backend works very well with the postman but when I just try to login from my front end, in the console.log I get the error message 'problem with cors'...
What am I missing?
**and here is the error message :
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/user/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.**

here is the code of the function that runs after the submit

Comment: You have to allow localhost in your backend cors config. If you are using express, try to see it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150051/how-to-enable-cors-nodejs-with-express

Answer (score 1):

- Add Proxy in package.json of front end application.

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

- Next instead of full uri in axios call just call it as

```
axios.post('/user/login')...
```

- Now inside the backend (node) directory add the following dependency using npm

```
npm install cors
```

- Now use this inside main server file i.e server.js like below

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't work yet. By the way, the cors is already installed and configured in the server.js

Comment: @MUHESI Can you post the additional details i.e what response you getting in network tab of api ?