# "POST http://localhost:5000 net err failed"

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to send a post request to a node server using axios, here's what I've done in react-js.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000', {
      firstName: 'Finn',
      lastName: 'Williams'
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

And here's what I've done in the server.

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const port = 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Every time I send the request, I get the following message in the console `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

What should I do to fix that?

Comment: The ports are different, they count as different origins.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable cors nodejs with express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150051/how-to-enable-cors-nodejs-with-express)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) npm package to configure your express HTTP server cors.

`npm install cors`

Then import CORS package in your express application file like that:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())

const app = express()
const port = 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Then in your request code, you should to request with GET method. You are using `axios.post()` which does POST request. And that will response you with 404 because you don't have `app.post('/')` route handler in your application. So the code should look like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())

const app = express()
const port = 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(Hello ${req.body.firstName} ${req.body.lastName}!`)`;
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install the `cors`

- npm install cors --save

after that you can add this code on server file

```
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors()) // Use this after the variable declaration
```

Comment: When I did that, I got POST http://localhost:5000/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You need to post to port `5000` and allow from origin with port `3000`. Different ports = different origin.

Comment: @Migo101 you need to use``axios.get()`` not ``axios.post()``. You don't have a ``app.post('/', (req, res) => { ... });`` POST route handler. That's why you also get 404.

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending CORS headers on your responses, so the requests are denied. This can be easily solved by:

1. Run `npm i cors`
2. Change your code to

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express()
const port = 5000;

app.use(cors());

// all the other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

This error basically occurs because of a security mechanism that browsers implement called the same-origin policy. It prevents any cross-domain communication which may lead to cyber attacks like **cross-site request forgery**.

While we develop backend APIs for our frontend apps, we have to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) in our backend server. To do that there are several libraries, the most common one is [Cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package. Install it and use it in your server app as follows-

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
```