# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. node backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have watched a tutorial to know how redux toolkit work after watching that he uses some online api providing service now when i am using it i need to customize it for my use so i have did change the name and the urls

here is my store.js

```
    import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {setupListeners} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
import { postApi } from './actions/productAction'

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer:{
        [postApi.reducerPath]:postApi.reducer
    },

    // middleware:(getDefaultMiddleware)=>getDefaultMiddleware().concat(postApi.middleware),

    // middleware is also created for us, which will allow us to take advantage of caching, invalidation, polling, and the other features of RTK Query.
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
  getDefaultMiddleware().concat(postApi.middleware),
})

setupListeners(store.dispatch)
```

Here i have the action file which is actually taking the action updating state

```
    import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const postApi = createApi({
    reducerPath:'postApi',//this is unique path which will tell the broweser where it need to store the cookie data
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl:'',
    }),
    endpoints:(builder)=>({
        getAllPost: builder.query({
            query:()=>({
                url:'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/products',
                method:'GET'
            })
        }),
        getPostById: builder.query({
            query: (id) =>({
                url:`posts/${id}`,
                method:'GET'
            })
        })
    })
})

export const {useGetAllPostQuery,useGetPostByIdQuery} = postApi
```

The place where i am calling this function is

```
import React from 'react'
import {useGetAllPostQuery} from '../../actions/productAction'
// import Card from '../../components/Card';

const HomePage = () => {

  console.log(useGetAllPostQuery())
  const responseInfo = useGetAllPostQuery()

  console.log("the response i am getting is",responseInfo)
  
  return (
    <>
    <h1>Hello worls</h1>
    
  </>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

my console where i am getting i dont why this error is coming
the request is rejcted at the same time my post man works on that
[image]

The error expanded image

[image]

The actual issue is

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with react and everything to do with your backend. Even if the resource is returning the correct access control header you still need to be handling `OPTIONS` requests from the browser preflight check.

Comment: And on how to easily enable CORS in  a node backend see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150051/how-to-enable-cors-nodejs-with-express