# How to fix cors error still getting it after adding set headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I have deployed my ecommerce website separately backend from frontend.  I added an API to make https requests from frontend to the backend so now I have a CORS problem.

This is my server.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const http = require('http')
require('dotenv').config()
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET)
require('./connection')
const server = http.createServer(app)
const { Server } = require('socket.io')
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors : {
    origin: ["https://mhtdistribution.netlify.app/", "http://localhost:3000"]
  },
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
})

app.use(cors({
  origin: ["https://mhtdistribution.netlify.app/", "http://localhost:3000"]
}))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    return res.sendStatus(200);
  }
  next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')))

const User = require('./models/User')
const Balance = require('./models/Balance')
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes')
const productRoutes = require('./routes/productRoutes')
const orderRoutes = require('./routes/orderRoutes')
const imageRoutes = require('./routes/imageRoutes')
const balanceRoutes = require('./routes/balanceRoutes')


    
// Add headers before the routes are defined
// app.use(cors, function (req, res, next) {
 
//   // Website you wish to allow to connect
//   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://mhtdistribution.netlify.app")

//   // Request methods you wish to allow
//   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE")

//   // Request headers you wish to allow
//   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization")

//   // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
//   // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
//   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true)

//   // Pass to next layer of middleware
//   next()
// })
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/users', userRoutes)
app.use('/products', productRoutes)
app.use('/orders', orderRoutes)
app.use('/images', imageRoutes)
app.use('/balance', balanceRoutes)

// app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  
//   // Website you wish to allow to connect
//   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

//   // Request methods you wish to allow
//   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE")

//   // Request headers you wish to allow
//   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization")

//   // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
//   // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
//   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true)

//   // Pass to next layer of middleware
//   next()
// });

app.post('/create-payment', async (req, res) => {
  const { amount } = req.body
  console.log(amount)
  try {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount,
      currency: 'usd',
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
    })
    res.status(200).json(paymentIntent);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message)
    res.status(400).json(e.message)
  }
})

//get Balance
// app.get('/balances', async (req, res)=>{
//      Balance.find().then(balance => res.json(balance)).catch(err => res.json(err))

// });

let port = process.env.PORT || 8080

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('server running at port', port)
})


app.set('socketio', io)
```

I added the headers to prevent CORS errors but still getting these errors.

This is my appapi.js file and it contains mutations that make the request from front to back

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { config } from "../config"

// create the api

export const appApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: "appApi",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: config.apiURL }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        signup: builder.mutation({
            query: (user) => ({
                url: "/users/signup",
                method: "POST",
                body: user,
            }),
        }),

        login: builder.mutation({
            query: (user) => ({
                url: "/users/login",
                method: "POST",
                body: user,
            }),
        }),
        // creating product
        createProduct: builder.mutation({
            query: (product) => ({
                url: "/products",
                body: product,
                method: "POST",
            }),
        }),

        deleteProduct: builder.mutation({
            query: ({ product_id, user_id }) => ({
                url: `/products/${product_id}`,
                body: {
                    user_id,
                },
                method: "DELETE",
                headers: {    
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
            }),
        }),

        updateProduct: builder.mutation({
            query: (product) => ({
                url: `/products/${product.id}`,
                body: product,
                method: "PATCH",
            }),
        }),

        //update balance 
        // updateBalance: builder.mutation({
        //     query: () => ({
        //         url: "/balance",
        //         method: "GET",
        //     }),
        // }),

        // add to cart
        addToCart: builder.mutation({
            
            query: (cartInfo) => ({
                url: "/products/add-to-cart",
                body: cartInfo,
                method: "POST",
            }),
        }),
        // remove from cart
        removeFromCart: builder.mutation({
            query: (body) => ({
                url: "/products/remove-from-cart",
                body,
                method: "POST",
            }),
        }),

        // increase cart
        increaseCartProduct: builder.mutation({
            query: (body) => ({
                url: "/products/increase-cart",
                body,
                method: "POST",
            }),
        }),

        // decrease cart
        decreaseCartProduct: builder.mutation({
            query: (body) => ({
                url: "/products/decrease-cart",
                body,
                method: "POST",
            }),
        }),
        // create order
        createOrder: builder.mutation({
            query: (body) => ({
                url: "/orders",
                method: "POST",
                body,
            }),
        }),
    }),
});

export const {
    useSignupMutation,
    useLoginMutation,
    useCreateProductMutation,
    useAddToCartMutation,
    useRemoveFromCartMutation,
    useIncreaseCartProductMutation,
    useDecreaseCartProductMutation,
    useCreateOrderMutation,
    useDeleteProductMutation,
    useUpdateProductMutation,
    useUpdateBalanceMutation,
} = appApi;

export default appApi;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

and this is the product Route js file at the backend

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const Product = require('../models/Product');
const User = require('../models/User');

//get products;
router.get('/', async(req, res)=> {
  try {
    const sort = {'_id': -1}
    const products = await Product.find().sort(sort);
    res.status(200).json(products);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e.message);
  }
})


//create product
router.post('/', async(req, res)=> {
  try {
    const {codeBarre,reference,name, description, price, quantite, category, images: pictures} = req.body;
    const product = await Product.create({codeBarre,reference,name, description, price, quantite, category, pictures});
    const products = await Product.find();
    res.status(201).json(products);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e.message);
  }
})


// update product

router.patch('/:id', async(req, res)=> {
  const {id} = req.params;
  try {
    const {codeBarre,reference,name, description, price, quantite, category, images: pictures} = req.body;
    const product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {codeBarre,reference,name, description, price, quantite, category, pictures});
    const products = await Product.find();
    res.status(200).json(products);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e.message);
  }
})


// delete product

router.delete('/:id', async(req, res)=> {
  const {id} = req.params;
  const {user_id} = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(user_id);
    if(!user.isAdmin) return res.status(401).json("You don't have permission");
    await Product.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    const products = await Product.find();
    res.status(200).json(products);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e.message);
  }
})


router.get('/:id', async(req, res)=> {
  const {id} = req.params;
  try {
    const product = await Product.findById(id);
    const similar = await Product.find({category: product.category}).limit(5);
    res.status(200).json({product, similar});
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e.message);
  }
});

router.get('/category/:category', async(req,res)=> {
  const {category} = req.params;
  try {
    let products;
    const sort = {'_id': -1}
    if(category == "all"){
      products = await Product.find().sort(sort);
    } else {
      products = await Product.find({category}).sort(sort)
    }
    res.status(200).json(products);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e.message);
  }
})

// cart routes

router.post('/add-to-cart', async(req, res)=> {
  const {userId, productId, price} = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    const userCart = user.cart;
    if(user.cart[productId]){
      userCart[productId] += 1;
    } else {
      userCart[productId] = 1;
    }
    userCart.count += 1;
    userCart.total = Number(userCart.total) + Number(price);
    user.cart = userCart;
    user.markModified('cart');
    await user.save();
    res.status(200).json(user);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e.message);
  }
})

router.post('/increase-cart', async(req, res)=> {
  const {userId, productId, price} = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    const userCart = user.cart;
    userCart.total += Number(price);
    userCart.count += 1;
    userCart[productId] += 1;
    user.cart = userCart;
    user.markModified('cart');
    await user.save();
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e.message);
  }
});

router.post('/decrease-cart', async(req, res)=> {
  const {userId, productId, price} = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    const userCart = user.cart;
    userCart.total -= Number(price);
    userCart.count -= 1;
    userCart[productId] -= 1;
    user.cart = userCart;
    user.markModified('cart');
    await user.save();
    res.status(200).json(user);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e.message);
  }
})

router.post('/remove-from-cart', async(req, res)=> {
  const {userId, productId, price} = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    const userCart = user.cart;
    userCart.total -= Number(userCart[productId]) * Number(price);
    userCart.count -= userCart[productId];
    delete userCart[productId];
    user.cart = userCart;
    user.markModified('cart');
    await user.save();
    res.status(200).json(user);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e.message);
  }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you please add an example call from the front-end?

Comment: yes sure so I have used mutations I will make screen shots so you can understand how does it work

Comment: this is my Appapi.js file

Comment: Either use a CORS middleware (preferable) or manually set CORS response headers, but do not do both. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow. Finally, edit your question and add the CORS error message.

Comment: how to use this cors middleware please guide me to some solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable cors nodejs with express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150051/how-to-enable-cors-nodejs-with-express). FYI your CORS `origin` values should **not** end with a `/`

Comment: Ok I will try to remove "/" and comeback with the result

Comment: Well It worked When I removed the "/" from the origin value thank you so much all of you,