Access to fetch has been blocked by CORS policy - Vite/React/Express
I'm using Vite with React/Express and started the app with npm run dev - running on http://localhost:5173 and using http://localhost:5000 for the backend in the meantime. When trying to test a post request using fetch(), I'm constantly getting the following error:

server/App.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user-routes');
const HttpError = require('./models/http-error');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');
    next();
})

app.use('/user', userRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new HttpError('Could not find this route', 404);
    next(error);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    if (res.headersSent) {
        return next(error);
    }
    res.status(error.code || 500);
    res.json({ message: error.message || 'An unknown error occurred' });
});

mongoose
    .connect('mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@ts-trainings.ic7mcip.mongodb.net/user?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=ts-trainings')
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(5000, () => {
            console.log('Server is running on port 5000');
            console.log('Connection Success');
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Connection Failed');
        console.log(err);
    });

user-routes.js:
const express = require("express");
const { check } = require("express-validator");

const userController = require("../controllers/user-controllers");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", userController.getUser);

router.post(
  "/signup",
  [
    check("firstname").not().isEmpty(),
    check("lastname").not().isEmpty(),
    check("email").normalizeEmail().isEmail(),
    check("username").not().isEmpty(),
    check("password").isLength({ min: 6 }),
  ],
  userController.signup
);

router.post("/login", userController.login);

module.exports = router;

user-controllers.js:
const login = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  let existingUser;

  try {
    existingUser = await User.findOne({ username: username });
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError("Login failed, please contact support", 500);
    return next(error);
  }

  if (!existingUser || existingUser.password !== password) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Invalid credentials, could not log you in.',
      401
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  res.json({ message: "Logged In" });
};

Frontend page:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Col, Form, InputGroup, Row, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';

import '../assets/css/AdminLogin.css';

const AdminLogin = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);
    const [alert, setAlert] = useState({ show: false, message: '', variant: '' });

    const handleLogin = async (event) => {
        const form = event.currentTarget;
        event.preventDefault();
        
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            setValidated(true);
            return;
        }
        
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/user/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
            });

            const result = await response.json();

            if (result.success) {
                setAlert({ show: true, message: 'Login successful!', variant: 'success' });
                // Redirect to a new page or take any other action
            } else {
                setAlert({ show: true, message: 'Invalid credentials. Please try again.', variant: 'danger' });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setAlert({ show: true, message: 'An error occurred. Please try again later.', variant: 'danger' });
        }
    };

    return (
        <Form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleLogin} className="loginForm">
            <Row className="mb-2">
                <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                    <InputGroup hasValidation>
                        <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroupPrepend">@</InputGroup.Text>
                        <Form.Control
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Username"
                            aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend"
                            value={username}
                            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                            required
                        />
                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                            Enter a username
                        </Form.Control.Feedback>
                    </InputGroup>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group as={Col} md="6" controlId="validationCustom01">
                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        required
                    />
                    <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                        Enter a password
                    </Form.Control.Feedback>
                </Form.Group>
            </Row>
            {alert.show && (
                <Alert variant={alert.variant} onClose={() => setAlert({ show: false })} dismissible>
                    {alert.message}
                </Alert>
            )}
            <div className='buttonContainer'>
                <Row>
                    <Col className="text-center">
                        <Button className="mainButton mt-3" variant="outline-info" size="lg" href="/register">
                            Register Instead
                        </Button>
                    </Col>
                    <Col className="text-center">
                        <Button className="mainButton mt-3" type="submit" variant="outline-warning" size="lg">{' '}
                            Login
                        </Button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        </Form>
    );
};

export default AdminLogin;

Any guidance would be appreciated.

try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150051/how-to-enable-cors-nodejs-with-express

To solve the CORS policy issue, you may consider the below steps.
Run this command in your server npm i cors to install the CORS package in your server app.
Then use CORS in server/App.js
Require CORS const cors = require('cors')
Now, add this code below this code const app = express();
// CORS options to allow requests from frontend running on port 5500
const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173', // Allow only requests from this origin
    methods: 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE', // Allow only these methods
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'] // Allow only these headers
};`

// Use CORS middleware with specified options
`app.use(cors(corsOptions));`

I hope this code solve your error.

