# How to avoid CORS issue in PWA

Tags: html, amazon-s3, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

We started implementing PWA, As part of the implementation, I am importing manifest.json from the amazon s3 bucket. Getting following error.

> Failed to load https://abcdefghij.com/static/pwa/Manifest.json:No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested

I had written following code in index.html file

```
 <link rel="manifest" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://abcdefghij.com/static/pwa/Manifest.json"/>
```

will be thankful, if someone helps.

Comment: You need to setup CORS for the particular s3 bucket in which you have the manifest.json file

Comment: I am not sure, but you can set up content-security-policy for manifest source?
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="manifest-src  https://abcdefghij.com">`

Answer (score 0):

Does your https://abcdefghij.com/ server support cross-origin request?

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend disabling CORS.But you can white list Few sources using S3 buckets. CORS Has to be set on server side [you can use this as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393256/express-cors-domain-whitelist)  assuming  you are using Node

[For S3 use this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)