# no jwt token Authorization in header when it is an external source with angular2

Tags: angular, http, header, authorization, jwt

I am having this code (angular2) :

```
let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    headers.append('Authorization',  this.authService.currentUser.token)
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get(this.url + 'quote/' , options)
```

when `this.url = '/'` (local request), I have Authorization in header:
[image]

---

When `this.url = 'http://212.227.201.82/'`, Authorization token disappear.

[image]

How Can I include headers Authorization for external request?
Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 1):

I have founded the issue!
It is not from Front end, but backend! [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (Cross-origin resource sharing) must be enabled in the API

EG with ExpressJS:

```
$ npm install cors
```

Simple Usage (Enable All CORS Requests)

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})
```

Reference: [Allow multiple CORS domain in express js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988071/allow-multiple-cors-domain-in-express-js) / [How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors) / https://github.com/expressjs/cors