# Unable to fetch JSON from Express server using Fetch api

Tags: javascript, express, cors, es6-promise, fetch-api

In Express server running on port 8080 I have;

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8081");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Request from port 8081

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/...')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        let jsonStr = JSON.stringify(json);
        console.log(jsonStr)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

Error I get:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/...' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

If I simply manually enter express url on browser I see the JSON I'm trying to fetch.

I have read multiple post to resolve this issue but I still can't seem to be able to resolve it.

How should I fetch to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching from a different port (8081) and that's why you're getting the CORS error message. Change the Access Control policy as follows:

```
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:*");
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988071/allow-multiple-cors-domain-in-express-js) can come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cors` to get rid of this;

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

Comment: @Vid I did try installing and using cors without success

Comment: I doubt you may be initializing cors after the API routes. Please check.

Comment: @Vid, Yes not longer getting the same error when initializing cors before the rest but I'm getting undefined for JSON