# How to allow express backend REST API to set cookie in a react frontend which is using axios?

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, axios, jwt

### Backend

I am trying make a JWT cookie based authentication work. I am currently performing the following cookie setting as part of a login route in the backend API.

```js
res.cookie('authCookie', token, {maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true});
```

Later when I am auth(ing) any other requests, I am reading off of this cookie and testing it in a `passport-jwt` strategy.

I have gotten this work in postman - when I perform a login and access a secured route - it works perfectly fine + the cookie is also getting set in postman.

### Frontend

Now, I am performing the following call stack in the frontend just to test the working,

```js
axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login", logInParams, config)
    .then(result => {
        // User is logged in so push them to the  respective dashboard
        console.log(result);
        axios.get("http://localhost:3001/user/profile")
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        return;
    });
```

So basically, I log the user in and that works perfectly fine - I am getting a JSON response as intended, but the call is supposed to set a cookie which it is not and hence the next `axios.get` call is not returning successfully. Though for some reason I see `session` cookie and a `CSRF` cookie. Only this `authCookie` or the jwt-cookie is not getting set.

### Some extra details

I am using cors with default parameters - could this be an error of this? Or is there any changes I have to do with axios? I have seen some answers and being new to MERN I don't really understand them. Does someone know about this or have experienced it and solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it - it seems to be an issue with how cors works and I am adding the following answer to help anyone else coming across it. Thank me later :)

### Server Side

You will have a cors in your server that looks like this,

```
app.use(cors());
```

You will have to set `credentials` to true and set the `allowedHeaders` and `origin` as follows,

```
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000']
}));
```

This is because normally cookies are not allowed to be set in the browser if the server and the client are in the same port. To handle this the above is required on the server side.

### Client Side

We also have to pass the cookies when we are sending the request and to do this with `axios` just add the following in the `index.js` of your  react app as so,

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the server from a different port than the one that provides the client (i.e: webpack-dev-server running on `localhost:3000` and Express server on `localhost:3001`)? This looks like a `same-site` cookie issue. In the latest versions of some browsers such as Chrome cookie setting is being blocked when this one comes from a different origin site. This is due to security concerns; you can learn more about same-site cookies [here](https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/).

The change made in the browsers is related to the default value they give to a cookie policy property called `same-site`. The old workaround was treating all the cookies from a different origin as `None` by default, but last year it changed to consider the `same-site` policy as `Lax` when no `same-site` policy was not explicitly provided by the server. This is a desirable behaviour from the browser because it helps at preventing third party sites making use of the cookie provided by the server, but you can edit it by different ways:

- Changing the default same-site policy of your browser settings (the article about same site cookies explains).
- Sending a `same-site:'None'` from the server. [Express has a way to do so explaind on its docs](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html). Keep in mind browsers also have a new policy to ignore `same-site:'None'` when the cookie is not marked as `Secure`, what demands the use of `HTTPS` (I guess this behaviour can be edited in your browser settings if you want to check while using `HTTP`).

Obviously, any strategy that demands the users to change their browser settings is a no-go, so running `HTTPS` with `Secure` cookies is mandatory for `same-site:'None'`.

You always have the approach of making both browser and client same origin, so you won't have any issues at all with `same-site` (i.e. the Express server returning the index.html of the production build of your client as its main static). I haven't found any way to configure CORS module to have a default same site cookies policy (or its sole use as middleware to change it), likely not its purpose, but you can try by [adding a dynamic origin config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988071/allow-multiple-cors-domain-in-express-js).

As far as I've seen, [Postman does not support the same-site cookie property yet](https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003703065-What-cookie-properties-aren-t-supported-), so that would explain why is it working on Postman but not on the browser.

Comment: Hi! I have figured it out. Thanks for your help <3. I have added my approach as my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should write send('cookies are set') at the end  in res.cookie('authCookie', token, {maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true});

Comment: I am not sure how that would help. Can you please be more clear?

Comment: I mean you do not send response to client